# Gradle Jar - Include dependencies' classes

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies, bundle

I'm working on a server application and using gradle for this. If i run "bundle", gradle creates a jar file which includes all compiled java classes of my project. But, obviously, you cannot run this jar because of the missing dependencies.

I currently these own task:

```
task bundleJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'your.own.start.main.class'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

But this includes "ALL" dependencies classes. **It is possible to integrate only classes which are needed by my application? Are they any problems with reflections?**

Another thing I thought about. Some libraries disallow to ship them in another application. So I only provide the source code to my users. They download it and execute the gradle task. **This should be ok, shouldn't it?**
**Is it better to bunld eeverything in one jar, or is it possible to create a seperate folder for needed classes?**

Thx:)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you do `configurations.compile.collect` so you will zip everything from the compile scope. you could change that with the class declared from your runtime scope (`configurations.runtime.collect`). sure it would mean that those classes have already been downloaded when you are doing the build.